# In Java, how to write HTML code in a POST request's body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a SpringBoot project, I have a POST route that receives HTML code and sends out an email with the HTML code as content.

I tried to use Postman to test it, and pasted the HTML code into the Body Json's `payload` field, as shown below:

[image]

But the format is messed up. It seems that I need to escape the quotes or something.

I am wondering how to do it conveniently?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply use an online JSON encoder...

Comment: Thank you... Do you want to make it an answer? I will accept it. @Yann39

Comment: No need, thanks, this is quite a basic encoding question and I think it should rather be deleted to avoid cluttering the site ;) If you prefer not to delete it feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Yann39 indicated, I need to use an online JSON encoder